# rsync between two docker container

Tags: docker, rsync

I'm setting a backup/ sync within an Ubuntu network using rsync.

Assume that a Desktop (Ubuntu 18.04)-ip: 10.0.0.13
Running a docker with two Containers :

```
 Client_A: 2001 -> 22/tcp , 8001 -> 80/tcp  
 Client_B: 2002 -> 22/tcp , 8002 -> 80/tcp
```

All 3 images are ubuntu, apache2 installed and running

dir:

```
DesktopOS        Container1         Container2
10.0.0.13:80     10.0.0.13:8001     10.0.0.13:8002  
⊢var             ⊢var               ⊢var             
  ⊢www             ⊢www               ⊢www           
    ⊢html            ⊢html              ⊢html          
      ⊢1.txt           ⊢2.txt             ⊢3.txt
```

all three txt can be accessed in browser

---

When i try to pull 3.txt to Container1:

```
rsync -av -e 'ssh -p 2002' --rsh=ssh user@10.0.0.13/var/www/html/ ~/BACKUP/
```

1.txt has received.

---

How to access the 3.txt in Container1?

Please use the IP Address since I am simulating a real network, maybe 1 docker on 1 device in the real world.

Comment: This doesn't sound like a typical Docker setup.  Normally a Docker container would _only_ run, say, Apache (and not sshd), and if you needed to share files between the host and a container, you'd use the `docker run -v` option for it.  A container's local filesystem shouldn't have anything that needs to be backed up and that you wouldn't mind losing when you need to `docker rm` it.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found I installed ssh only, doesn't install the ssh-server.
Otherwise, the firewall blocks the access.

```
#find out port 22, 2002, 2001 etc. 
#from netstat result, is it listening?
netstat | grep 2002
```

Install ssh server

```
sudo apt install tasksel
sudo tasksel install openssh-server
```

for Firewall:

```
sudo ufw allow 2001,2002
```

and it solved, thanks for your patients who try to answer me.